# How to reverse value in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

hello I have values like this

```
1-10
2-3
901-321
```

I want to get the reverse values for example like this

```
10-1
3-2
321-901
```

I have tried this

```
  var str = "1-18";
 var newString = "";
    for (var i = str.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        newString += str[i];
    }
    return newString;
```

But it gives me `81-1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = "12-5"
console.log(a.split('-').reverse().join('-'))
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead, use `String.split()`, `Arrary.reverse()` and `Arrary.join()`:

```js
var str = '901-321';

var strArray = str.split('-'); // ['901', '321']

var strArrayReversed = strArray.reverse(); // ['321', '901']

var result = strArrayReversed.join('-'); // '321-901'

console.log('result = ', result);

// You can do all these steps above in one go as:

var result2 = str.split('-')
  .reverse()
  .join('-');
  
console.log('result2 = ', result2);
```

MDN Docs:

- [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)
- [`Array.prototype.reverse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse)
- [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

Comment: @charlietfl Good catch! I have updated my answer now.

Answer (score 3):

Can split on the `-` to create array ,  reverse the array and join it back into string

```js
var str = "1-18",
    newStr = str.split('-').reverse().join('-');

console.log(newStr)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `split` method to divide the string in two, and then use the second part before the first, like this:

```
var str = "1-18";
var l = str.split("-");
return l[1] + "-" + l[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

You could replace the string by swapping the values.

```js
var string = '901-321';

console.log(string.replace(/(.+)-(.+)/, '$2-$1'));
```